# How to do auto adjustment in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to use Pyqt to create one main widget and several frames. In each frame, I had some QLabels, QlineEdit objects.Before I always set fixed size to each one. When I use different computers, it shows differently depends on the resolution, the size of the screen. Is there a way to make all those objects follow the change with the frame and main widget?

My GUI is not completed yet and here is the link to the image to show what I described above.

[image]

Comment: You should look up layouts and size policies in Qt.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew a little about Vbox and Hbox layout functions, so without using these two functions, I cannot achieve auto adjustment in Pyqt?

Comment: @Dogod. Layouts are a fundamental part of Qt. Please read a [basic tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/) on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "make all those objects follow the change with the frame and main widget", I assume you are talking about allowing your widgets to expand or shrink depending on the size of the main widget. To do this, you should check out the [setSizePolicy()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy) method for those widgets.

Ultimately, you will want to do something like `scope_mem_le.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)` for each of your widgets, where you may choose a different policy for each widget as appropriate.

You may also want to consider checking out PyQt Designer, which will provide a GUI interface for designing UIs, including the ability to set size policies for each of your widgets. This is often much easier and faster than trying to do this programmatically.